# InitializeApp firebase in react native: Error "Unexpected token

Tags: firebase, react-native, authentication, expo

Got error while initializing Firebase configuration in expo react native. Unexpected token ";"

Enviroment:
Expo development
React native
firebase
visual studio code editor

What I want:
I am new , learning how to authenticate /login in react native application using firebase email/password method.

What I did:
In the code editor tool--> app.js--> I imported the firebase , created a const to define the firebase config parameters.

After that, I tried to initialize firebase .

What is the issue:

## When I ran the app on my phone , the following error occurred.

SyntaxError: C:\Users\Jituni\bholmentorworld\App.js: Unexpected token, expected ";" (32:23)

30 | };
  31 |

> 32 |  firebase.initializeApp{firebaseConfig};
>        |                        ^
>     33 | 
>     34 | export default class App extends React.Component{
>
> ## 35 |

```
[import React from "react";
import { Image, Button, TextInput, ScrollView, Stylesheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

import * as firebase from 'firebase';


const firebaseConfig={
  apiKey:"AIzaSyDimdV7iWkVaLKpQVqt82_TiSuRA0NBAOE",
  authDomain:"firebaseapp",
  databaseURL:"mentordunia",
  projectId:"mentordunia",
  storageBucket:"",
  messagingSenderId:"1055433782606",
  appId:"b308d4b9d990db06",
};

 firebase.initializeApp{firebaseConfig};

export default class App extends React.Component{


render() {
return <AppContainer/>;
 }
};][1]
```

Expected result:
Should not receive error to initialize firebase

Actual result:
Error in initialing firebase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using a linter to catch any possible error, I personally use eslint with vs code.

`firebase.initializeApp{firebaseConfig};` should be `firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);`